# Naming suggestions for a function returning parent prototype

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I'm having a naming trouble with a function which returns parent prototype of specified object. It's being used like this:

```
# Pseudo Code

MyClass
{
  super(MyClass,this).constructor.call(....
```

The problem is that I want to use a word which is as superior as "super", but "super" is reserved even it's undefined. Now I'm using "parent", but the window object has a property named parent. I hate Javascript.

What should I name this function? Names have to start with lowercase and have to be short.

Comment: `superclass` is too long? That's what YUI uses.

Comment: superclass sounds good but this function doesn't return a class. it returns a prototype object.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions:

```
base
myparent
foundation
root
ancestor
```

Answer (score 1):

How about "root", "source", or "origin"? None of those are reserved in JavaScript.

Comment: There may be more than one parents and this function returns the prototype on one level up, not root. Origin sounds good but I guess I can't use this too because of the same reason..

Answer (score 1):

How about `proto`?

Comment: proto sounds good, too, but it doesn't include any meaning about the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

For `class` it is common to use "klass" or "clazz", so why not "zuper"?
It might even cheer you up a little when you're doing battle with the loathsome javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

The following are some synonyms of reserved keywords in English:

```
class      -> construct
extends    -> augments
super      -> uber      -> hyper
```

I'm still looking for synonyms for my own project. Let me know if you find one for `implements`.